# python write input by user without dirty char

Tags: python-2.7

When I ask in my python progam to store one variabile with raw_input:

```
new_app = raw_input("Insert something: " )
```

during the execution I wrong write it and use backspace button to correct:

```
Insert something : test(correct)
```

the data is stored with `???` (one `?` for only backspace used)

how can I fix this problem?
thanks in advice

Comment: Are you using some unusual terminal settings or perhaps using ssh to a remote machine?

Comment: now i test this script in a linux server, and i write the string by terminal

Comment: Ok, that was just a hunch. Your code works on my machine.